# Error Installing BDB on Ubuntu 15.04 (64 Bit), "Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

OS: Ubuntu 15.04 (64 Bit)

Ruby Version: ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]

While running gem install bdb, i get the following error, can anyone point out the possible cause of the error, or provide pointers towards resolution?

```
Error installing bdb:
Error: Failed to build gem native extension
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151216-2783-1lobclo.rb extconf.rb
checking for db_version() in -ldb-5.1... no
checking for db_version() in -ldb-5.0... no
checking for db_version() in -ldb-4.9... no
checking for db_version() in -ldb-4.8... no
checking for db_version() in -ldb-4.7... no
checking for db_version() in -ldb-4.6... no
checking for db_version() in -ldb-4.5... no
checking for db_version() in -ldb-4.4... no
checking for db_version() in -ldb-4.3... no
checking for db_version() in -ldb-4.2... no
Writing bdb_aux._c (defines), this takes a while
don't know how to handle DB_DEGREE_2 DB_READ_COMMITTED, guessing UINT
don't know how to handle DB_DIRTY_READ DB_READ_UNCOMMITTED, guessing UINT
don't know how to handle DB_HEAP_RID_SZ (sizeof(db_pgno_t) + sizeof(db_indx_t)), guessing UINT

wrote 501 defines
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling bdb.c
bdb.c: In function ‘raise_error’:
bdb.c:82:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
  VALUE cl;
  ^
bdb.c:84:0: warning: "eDbE_create" redefined
 #define eDbE_create(n,c) case DB_##n: cl = eDbE_##c; break;
 ^
bdb.c:50:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define eDbE_create(n,c) VALUE eDbE_##c;
 ^
bdb.c: In function ‘db_open’:
bdb.c:266:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘raise’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         raise(0, "txn is closed");
         ^
bdb.c: In function ‘db_get_re_len’:
bdb.c:330:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
  int rv = dbh->db->get_re_len(dbh->db,&re_len);
  ^
bdb.c: In function ‘db_set_encrypt’:
bdb.c:1074:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
     u_int32_t flags=0x00000001; //DB_ENCRYPT_AES
     ^
In file included from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:0,
                 from ./bdb.h:5,
                 from bdb.c:8:
bdb.c: In function ‘assoc_rescue’:
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:909:30: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
 #define RSTRING(obj) (R_CAST(RString)(obj))
                              ^
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:903:30: note: in definition of macro ‘R_CAST’
 #define R_CAST(st)   (struct st*)
                              ^
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:679:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘RSTRING’
      RSTRING(str)->as.heap.ptr)
      ^
bdb.c:1200:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘RSTRING_PTR’
   rb_warn(RSTRING_PTR(message));
           ^
bdb.c: In function ‘assoc_callback’:
bdb.c:1248:18: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       for (i=0; i<skey->size; i++) {
                  ^
bdb.c:1249:30: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
         assoc_key(skey->data + i * sizeof(DBT), (VALUE)RARRAY_PTR(keys)[i]);
                              ^
bdb.c: In function ‘db_stat’:
bdb.c:2141:3: warning: enumeration value ‘DB_HEAP’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
   switch(dbtype) {
   ^
bdb.c: In function ‘env_txn_stat’:
bdb.c:2299:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   for (i=0; i<statp->st_nactive; i++) {
              ^
bdb.c: In function ‘env_get_data_dirs’:
bdb.c:2751:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
  VALUE rb_data_dirs = rb_ary_new2(ln);
  ^
bdb.c: In function ‘env_set_encrypt’:
bdb.c:2912:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   u_int32_t flags=0x00000001; //DB_ENCRYPT_AES
   ^
bdb.c: In function ‘env_repmgr_set_local_site’:
bdb.c:3005:15: error: ‘DB_ENV’ has no member named ‘repmgr_set_local_site’
   rv = eh->env->repmgr_set_local_site(eh->env, StringValuePtr(host), NUM2UINT(port), 0);
               ^
bdb.c: In function ‘env_repmgr_add_remote_site’:
bdb.c:3024:15: error: ‘DB_ENV’ has no member named ‘repmgr_add_remote_site’
   rv = eh->env->repmgr_add_remote_site(eh->env, StringValuePtr(host), NUM2UINT(port), &eidp, 0);
               ^
bdb.c: In function ‘env_get_lg_bsize’:
bdb.c:3119:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘UINT2FIX’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   return UINT2FIX(size);
   ^
bdb.c: In function ‘Init_bdb’:
bdb.c:3331:0: warning: "eDbE_create" redefined
 #define eDbE_create(n,c) eDbE_##c = rb_define_class_under(mBdb, #c, eDbError);
 ^
bdb.c:84:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define eDbE_create(n,c) case DB_##n: cl = eDbE_##c; break;
 ^
bdb.c:3424:0: warning: "ENV_LOG_CONFIG_FUNC" redefined
 #define ENV_LOG_CONFIG_FUNC(name,cnst) \
 ^
bdb.c:2533:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define ENV_LOG_CONFIG_FUNC( name, cnst) \
 ^
Makefile:206: recipe for target 'bdb.o' failed
make: *** [bdb.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```